# Array in Hashes to single hash

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I've got a not stadnard Array in Hash which I would like to convert it to just single hash without the Array.

Array in Hashes:

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[{:W31=>0.1e1}, {:W31=>0.3e1}], {:W32=>0.1e1}], {:W32=>0.3e1}], {:W33=>0.1e1}], {:W33=>0.3e1}], {:W34=>0.1e1}], {:W34=>0.3e1}], {:W35=>0.5e1}], {:W35=>0.5e1}], {:W36=>0.4e1}], {:W36=>0.6e1}], {:W37=>0.1e1}], {:W37=>0.61e2}], {:W38=>0.1e1}], {:W38=>0.6e1}]
```

And what I need is they key and value in one hash:

```
{:W31=>0.1e1,:W32=>0.1e1, :W33=>0.1e1}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the criteria to decide what should remain in the hash if you have `{ W31: 0.1e1 }` and `{ W31: 0.6e1 }`?

Comment: _"Array in Hashes"_ – looks more like hashes in arrays.

Comment: BTW, where does that nested structure come from? Maybe you can avoid creating the nesting in the first place.

Comment: I'm downvoting and voting to close, not because your question is unclear, which it is, but because you have had ample time to respond to the above requests for clarification and have not done so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flatten to put everything on one level :

```
[
  [[[[[[[[[[[[[[{:W31=>0.1e1}, {:W31=>0.3e1}], {:W32=>0.1e1}], {:W32=>0.3e1}], {:W33=>0.1e1}], {:W33=>0.3e1}], {:W34=>0.1e1}], {:W34=>0.3e1}], {:W35=>0.5e1}], {:W35=>0.5e1}], {:W36=>0.4e1}], {:W36=>0.6e1}], {:W37=>0.1e1}], {:W37=>0.61e2}], {:W38=>0.1e1}], {:W38=>0.6e1}
].flatten
```

And you'll get :

> [{"W31"=>1}, {"W31"=>3}, {"W32"=>1}, {"W32"=>3}, {"W33"=>1}, {"W33"=>3}, {"W34"=>1}, {"W34"=>3}, {"W35"=>5}, {"W35"=>5}, {"W36"=>4}, {"W36"=>6}, {"W37"=>1}, {"W37"=>61}, {"W38"=>1}, {"W38"=>6}]

then reduce in one hash :

```
[
  {"W31"=>1}, {"W31"=>3}, {"W32"=>1}, {"W32"=>3}, {"W33"=>1}, {"W33"=>3}, {"W34"=>1}, {"W34"=>3}, {"W35"=>5}, {"W35"=>5}, {"W36"=>4}, {"W36"=>6}, {"W37"=>1}, {"W37"=>61}, {"W38"=>1}, {"W38"=>6}
].reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

to get :

> {"W31"=>3, "W32"=>3, "W33"=>3, "W34"=>3, "W35"=>5, "W36"=>6, "W37"=>61, "W38"=>6}

Comment: Please update the answer to make flatten and reduce visible without scrolling.

Comment: Sorry @razvans and thx spickermann. As you can see I'm pretty new on writing answers. I'll do better next time.